# Same Document inserted multiple times due to multiple request of creation/updation

Tags: java, mongodb

Suppose, there is a event-producer code to create/update document in mongo and multiple events were produced at the same time.
Mongo received these events and created multiple document with same data.
Is there a way to prevent this????

Comment: You can do a few things here.  The two most obvious options I can think of are to check to make sure the document doesn't already exist or run a create/update command where the document is updated if it already exists and creates only if the document doesn't exist.

Comment: Another option: Give your documents IDs that reflect their identity and use `insert` with the `upsert` option, so you update if it exists and insert if it doesn't. If you have IDs that reflect identity, you could also of course just check if the doc exists before you insert.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a unique index which prevents insertion of duplicate data.  Be aware that **checking if the document doesn't exist already will not solve your problem** as you require events occur concurrently without causing data inconsistency or conflicts.  Creating unique indexes will address the race conditions you are having issues with.

Reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/#concurrency-control